# ContextConfiguration dosen't work JUnit4 class for testbench

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, automated-tests, spring-boot-test, vaadin8

Hello I am finding the solution for getting the bean instantiated given in @ContextConfiguration when we run the Vaadin test case with spring boot.

Here is some piece of the code which I have configured.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = UIConfiguration.class)
public abstract class BaseTestCase extends TestBenchTestCase {
//code stuff
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/spring/application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ui", excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION))
@EnableAsync
@EnableI18N
public class UIConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
//block of code
}
```

Comment: I am looking for @RunWith(Junit4.class) only

Comment: I assume you're getting NPEs as nome of the application context is configured and requires the `RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`?

Comment: I already have a configuration class as I showed here where I have @EnableI18N annotation and a messageResource bundle bean so the thing is I just wanted that bean instantiated using junit4.class which is not happening as it only makes beans of test class while going with springJunitRunner class the whole spring boot project is started which I don't want so the thing is that either I can have something to resist to start the whole spring project by springJunitRunner class or else I can have some thing with junit4 class.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `ClassRule` and `Rule` Spring provide if you do not want to use the `SpringRunner`

```
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

See the java doc for more details,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html

> SpringClassRule is a custom JUnit TestRule that supports class-level features of the Spring TestContext Framework in standard JUnit tests by means of the TestContextManager and associated support classes and annotations.
>
> In contrast to the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, Spring's rule-based JUnit support has the advantage that it is independent of any Runner and can therefore be combined with existing alternative runners like JUnit's Parameterized or third-party runners such as the MockitoJUnitRunner.
>
> In order to achieve the same functionality as the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, however, a SpringClassRule must be combined with a SpringMethodRule, since SpringClassRule only supports the class-level features of the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.